# Uncaught ReferenceError: onSelect is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM852 :14)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am getting this error in my console,

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: onSelect is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM998 :14)
```

my list data in .html file

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#" onclick="onSelect('Recipe')">Recipe</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#" onclick="onSelect('Shoppinglist')" id="ShoppingOnSelect">Shopping List</a></li>
            </ul>
```

On calling upon this function, My Typescript file in angular js,

```
export class HeaderComponent{
    @Output() featureSelected = new EventEmitter<String>();

    onSelect(feature: string){
        console.log(feature)
        this.featureSelected.emit(feature);
    }

}
```

The Onselect function itself is not running in the console when I clicked the onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `(click)`

```
<li><a href="#" (click)="onSelect('Recipe')">Recipe</a></li>
```

If you want to prevent the `href="#"` reloading the page:

```
<li><a href="#" (click)="!!onSelect('Recipe')">Recipe</a></li>
```

And also you can use replace `href="#"` with `[routerLink]=""` which is an alternative

```
<li><a [routerLink]="" (click)="!!onSelect('Recipe')">Recipe</a></li>
```